# Capacity exceeded error while using tikz package

Tags: tikz-qtree, qtree

Whenever I'm using tikz package as shown below it is showing that "!Tex capacity exceeded. What to do?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I'm sure you would add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. But something goes wrong, i can't see it, please add it again. Then we will find the problem. You are welcome.

Comment: either you have a _really really_ complicated tikz expression or (most likely) you have an error in code you have not shown. You need to show the code that makes the error message.

Comment: `qtree` is not a Ti*k*Z package. `tikz-qtree` is. Are you really using both?